# Java Custom Class Not Found: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, javac

I have the following `Subset.java` file:

```
package week2;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;

public class Subset {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        RandomizedQueue<String> randQueue = new RandomizedQueue<String>();
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            randQueue.enqueue(StdIn.readString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            StdOut.println(randQueue.dequeue());
        }
    }

}
```

There is also a `RandomizedQueue.java` in the same folder. However, when I run `javac-algs4 Subset.java` in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Subset.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        RandomizedQueue<String> randQueue = new RandomizedQueue<String>();
        ^
  symbol:   class RandomizedQueue
  location: class Subset
Subset.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        RandomizedQueue<String> randQueue = new RandomizedQueue<String>();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class RandomizedQueue
  location: class Subset
2 errors
```

(Please excuse me, I am brand new to Java.)

Comment: Try using an IDE. It'll point out the error before you attempt to manually compile the code

Comment: I am using Eclipse as well. It doesn't show an error before compilation, but when I send it in for grading (through coursera) I'm getting that error.

Comment: I don't know what `javac-algs4` does, but you have to compile all classes together. This is called building the classpath

Comment: @cricket_007 my apologies

Comment: It seems like `javac-algs4` just compiles with the given `algs4.jar` library. When I run with just `javac` I just get errors that the `StdIn` and `StdOut` methods don't exist.

Comment: If we read the duplicate, you'll see "If you have never compiled Bar and you run javac Foo.java, you are liable to find that the compiler can't find the symbol Bar", and that's what's happening here

Comment: Oh, if you are exporting a jar file, then you'll need to check all related classes, and that might not include `edu.princeton.cs.algs4`, but I'm sure the coursera course probably gives better instructions

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any real instructions. Also, I've read through the proposed duplicate several times and really don't see what I need to do to get this to work.